# Living in a neighborhood between a suburb and "the woods"

Tags: vocabulary

Is there a specific way to describe a very green suburban neighborhood, which has vegetation that looks natural/wild and relatively a lot of room between each house? It is just 1 mile away from the local main street.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about: https://goo.gl/maps/S12xc8ABkDtKr5Jt5

[image: Illustration]

Looking up "green suburb" I get mostly pictures of carefully planned areas with lined-up homes.

Comment: Tree-lines streets? Woodsy towns?

Comment: This would be classed as 'out in the country' in the UK, and a caveat 'barely a mile from the town centre' added.

Comment: There's probably a big difference between US and UK and other English. Things aren't always cut and dried. There may not be a particular term for this, you just describe it as well as you can. In US English maybe just 'suburbs with a lot of undeveloped area' (depending on how close it is to the main city. 'Exurbs' is a relatively rare term for areas associated with a large central city but somewhat remote.

Comment: I believe that such 'suburbs' are known as 'exurbs'.  But this word hardly captures the aura of such a rural exurb.  The UK is stuffed with them.  Drive through the Chiltern Hills or the Berkshire Downs and you you will find it difficult to credit that the 'villages' you pass  are stuffed with with the weekday commuter passengers on the trains in to London.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Britain such areas are known as *Leafy Suburbia*, or *Leafy Suburbs*.

To start with a dictionary example:

> Suburbia = Uncountable Noun
>
> Journalists often use suburbia to refer to the suburbs of cities and large towns considered as a whole.
>
> "...images of bright summer mornings in **leafy suburbia**."

Countless examples exist that demonstrate a wide understanding of the term:

> "Leafy Suburban Bed and Breakfast"
>
> [Booking dot Com](https://www.booking.com/hotel/gb/leafy-suburban-bed-and-breakfast.en-gb.html)

> "Fear stalks the teenagers of leafy suburbia"
>
> [Irish Catholic](https://www.irishcatholic.com/fear-stalks-the-teenagers-of-leafy-suburbia/)

> "Living in a pleasant leafy suburb which you dislike can be as bad for your health as living in a crime-ridden slum, a study has found."
>
> [Daily Mail](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-6439065/Living-leafy-suburb-dislike-bad-health.html)